# C# Executando um comando DDL

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Estou tentando executar o comando DDl abaixo que cria a tabela que necessito, mas mesmo não retornando erro a tabela não é criada, alguém teria alguma ideia de onde estou errando?

```
public const string scriptCriacao =  " if exists(select * from sys.objects as o where o.type =N'u' and o.name = N'Tuss_temp')"+
" drop table Tuss_temp "+
" Create Table Tuss_temp ( "+
" competencia         nvarchar(30), "+
" codigoTerminologia  float, "+
" nomeTerminologia    nvarchar(256), "+
" codigoTermo nvarchar(30), "+
" termo nvarchar(256), "+
" dtInicioVigencia datetime, "+
" dtFimVigencia datetime, "+
" dtFimImplementacao datetime, "+
" tipoAcao nvarchar(256), " +
")";

String connectionString = "Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog=PortalTISS_v3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=teste";

SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlConn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(scriptCriacao, SqlConn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Verifique se não é pela falta da porta do servidor na connectionString.

Comment: A conexão se estabelece não creio que seja isto, o problema é que eu executo o comando que não retorna erro, mas não efetiva a criação da tabela

Comment: A solução foi separar os scripts como pode ser visto abaixo

Comment: Repliquei exatamente seu exemplo, apenas alterando os dados da string de conexão e funcionou perfeitamente. Outra questão que você deve considerar são as permissões de acesso ao banco por outras aplicações.

Comment: public const string scriptDrop =  " if exists(select * from sys.objects as o where o.type =N'u' and o.name = N'Tuss_temp')"+
" drop table Tuss_temp ";

public const string scriptCreate =  " Create Table Tuss_temp ( "+
" competencia         nvarchar(30), "+
" codigoTerminologia  float, "+
" nomeTerminologia    nvarchar(256), "+
" codigoTermo nvarchar(30), "+
" termo nvarchar(256), "+
" dtInicioVigencia datetime, "+
" dtFimVigencia datetime, "+
" dtFimImplementacao datetime, "+
" tipoAcao nvarchar(256), " +
")";

Comment: Se possível, transforme seu comentário em resposta e assim deixarmos a pergunta como solucionada. Isso é essencial para deixar a fila de "sem resposta" idônea.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi o problema separando o script em dois como pode ser visto abaixo.

Obs,: A constante com o nome da tabela não tem relação com o problema em questão.
 O Ismael nos comentários não teve o problema para executar o script composto, eu creio que possa ser a versão do visual studio/C# que estou utilizando e/ou a versão do sql server quer faço uso.

Código.:

```
public const string NomeTabela = "Tuss_temp";

public const string scriptDrop = " if exists(select * from sys.objects as o where o.type =N'u' and o.name = N'"+ NomeTabela + "')" + " drop table " + NomeTabela;

public const string scriptCreate = " Create Table " + NomeTabela + " ( " +
    " competencia         nvarchar(30), " +
    " codigoTerminologia  float, " +
    " nomeTerminologia    nvarchar(256), " +
    " codigoTermo nvarchar(30), " +
    " termo nvarchar(256), " +
    " dtInicioVigencia datetime, " +
    " dtFimVigencia datetime, " +
    " dtFimImplementacao datetime, " +
    " tipoAcao nvarchar(256), " +
    ")";
```